# In Python can class.main() calls init method automatically?

Tags: python, object-oriented-analysis, python-class

I have a code snippet. Can anyone tell me whether `class.main` calls the initi method automatically? I cannot find a main method defined here, but calling to main. What is `TwitterStreamWarcIter.main` calling?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import absolute_import
from sfmutils.warc_iter import BaseWarcIter
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse


class TwitterStreamWarcIter(BaseWarcIter):
    def __init__(self, filepaths, limit_user_ids=None):
        BaseWarcIter.__init__(self, filepaths)
        self.limit_user_ids = limit_user_ids

    def _select_record(self, url):
        return url.startswith("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1")

    def _item_iter(self, url, json_obj):
        # Only want statuses, not deletes, stall_warnings, etc.
        if "id_str" in json_obj:
            yield "twitter_status", json_obj["id_str"], date_parse(json_obj["created_at"]), json_obj
        else:
            yield None, None, None, json_obj

    @staticmethod
    def item_types():
        return ["twitter_status"]

    @property
    def line_oriented(self):
        return True

    def _select_item(self, item):
        if not self.limit_user_ids or item.get("user", {}).get("id_str") in self.limit_user_ids:
            return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TwitterStreamWarcIter.main(TwitterStreamWarcIter)
```

Comment: Since `TwitterStreamWarcIter` doesn't contain a definition of `main`, it is looked for in the parent class `BaseWarcIter` instead.  (And if that doesn't contain it either, the search continues with *its* parent class, all the way back to `object` if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't call the `__init__` method automatically, it must be that `TwitterStreamWarcIter.main` calls the `main` function defined in the superclass `BaseWarcIter` which code you haven't provided. `TwitterStreamWarcIter` inherits this function and it is called by the piece of code `TwitterStreamWarcIter.main(TwitterStreamWarcIter)`